# Missing type arguments for generic class

Tags: java, generics

Using a library with an abstract class `A` and interfaces `I` and `J`, I get the following warning message when I extend / implement the class / interfaces:

> Missing type arguments for generic class J<T>.

As a MWE, the classes are as follows (T and S are generic type parameters):

```
public abstract class A {}

public interface I<T extends A> {
    public <S extends T> void doStuff(J<? super S> param);
}

public interface J<T extends A> {
    public void doOtherStuff();
}
```

Here are my classes:

```
public class AExtended extends A {}

public class IImplemented implements I<AExtended> {
    @Override
    public void doStuff(J param) {}
}
```

Explicitly using the class `AExtended` as below does not properly implement doStuff() from `I`:

```
public class IImplemented implements I<AExtended> {
    @Override
    public void doStuff(J<AExtended> param) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not overriding `doStuff` in `IImplemented` because the method is not generic and the type bounds are not present. This version of `doStuff` should work for you:

```
public <S extends AExtended> void doStuff(J<? super S> param) {}
```

Notice that since the type of `I` is `AExtended` it is used appropriately here, and the lower bound in the wildcard type for `J` is also included.

Answer (score 1):

try with:

```
public class IImplemented implements I<AExtended> {
   @Override
   public <S extends AExtended> void doStuff(J<? super S> param) {
      // ...
   }
}
```